# Redirect to a file named psfile

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Sorry for probably the seemingly dumb question, but I am rather confused on what my professor is asking, or how to test if I got the right answer. I have searched for similar questions but nothing seems to exactly relate. Here's the question

create a new file called program2.scr.

Change the permissions on this new file to add the execute bit for user, group, and owner.

Edit your new file using Gedit, VIM or VI and change it so it performs the following actions:

·       Using a line after #!/bin/bash, take the output of the ps –e command and pipe it to the sort command.

·       After it has been piped to the sort command, redirect that output to a file called psfile.

So far my code is this:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ps -e | sort > psfile
```

Is this all I need to do? Is it right? How to I test for the right output?

Comment: You can view the contents of a file by loading it into your editor or to dump it to the console just use the command `cat psfile` . `cat` takes a file and simply displays it to the console. Your script seems to be correct. You still need to run your script and as the assignment says you need to set the executable bit on the script.

Comment: Awesome, yea, I guess I did do it right. Thanks for the cat tip my man!

Comment: Yes, @user3530017 your script is correct and Michael's advice will be of use. Are you clear on changing the permissions?

Comment: extra credit if you read `man sort` and figure out how to sort by userID or process name ;-) >  For me, the biggest shell hip is use `set -vx` (or `set -x`) for debugging your shell scripts (once you start using variables). Good luck and keep posting.

Comment: @player3 Yea Michael's advice worked great! And yea I'm clear on how to change permissions.